# Adjust columns in a table

Tags: scripting, text-formatting

I have this table which is messed up

```
DB  Size_in_MB
foobar  11011.2
barfoo  4582.9
donkey  4220.8
shoryuken   555.9
hadouken    220.0
kong    214.8
super_mario_bros_p  211.1
```

there are unnecessary spaces between columns. I want to add `|` and adjust the spaces between columns. I tried `sed 's/\t/|/g'`and `sed 's/\t/\t|\t/g'` but did not work

```
DB  |   Size_in_MB
foobar  |   11011.2
barfoo  |   4582.9
donkey  |   4220.8
shoryuken   |   555.9
hadouken    |   220.0
kong    |   214.8
super_mario_bros_p  |   211.1
```

I want the table like this:

```
DB                  |  Size_in_MB
foobar              |  11011.2
barfoo              |  4582.9
donkey              |  4220.8
shoryuken           |  555.9
hadouken            |  220.0
kong                |  214.8
super_mario_bros_p  |  211.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the command `column` as follows:

```
cat file | sed 's/\t/,|,/g' | column -s ',' -t
DB                  |  Size_in_MB
foobar              |  11011.2
barfoo              |  4582.9
donkey              |  4220.8
shoryuken           |  555.9
hadouken            |  220.0
kong                |  214.8
super_mario_bros_p  |  211.1
```

Comment: thank you but this is still doesn't work. the columns are not adjusted!

Comment: Hi @Suzie I just ran the command and the results as listed in my answer. Run the command on your original table!

Comment: @Goro: also ran the command but did not work for me either. For me `sed 's/\s\+/,|,/g'` did the trick.

Comment: Ah Ok my bad, it worked I was doing it on the second table. Thank you for help!